# Maxwell's Equation

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

I was reading a book and I found the following equation. I'm not good at physics and I couldn't understand where does it come from, can anyone explain me why is it valid?
$$
\mathbf E = -\nabla\phi - \frac{\partial\mathbf A}{\partial t}
$$
Thank you!

Comment: If (as is obvious from your title) you knew the key phrase "Maxwell's Equation", why didn't you Google it?

Comment: This is pretty much an exact duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142906/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the definition of **A** and $\phi$ see [Magnetic potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential).

[image], definition for the magnetic vector potential **A**

[image], definition for the electric potential $\phi$

As you can see, by solving the system, you can obtain **A** and $\phi$ as functions of **B** and **E**.

Using the above definitions of the potentials, Maxwell's equations (see the demonstration from [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_potential#Magnetic_vector_potential) ) can be rewritten in a more compact form that can simplify various calculations.